# What should be done to access ubuntu apache server local url from virtual windows machine?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machines, virtualhost, ubuntu-10.04

What should be done to access Ubuntu apache server local url from virtual windows (VirtualBox OSE) machine ?

I have set virtual windows that can access ubuntu apache server, but after I delete windows.div with his folder  and restore it - its not working any more.

Maybe I should give more permission to  wrapper windows.div folder?

My computer:

computer OS :Ubuntu 10.04

virtual machine: VirtualBox OSE (I have 'Nat' option in network adapter)

virtual machine OS : windows xp

Example:

going inside virtual machine to firefox and inser address.me url.

result: Server not found

but when i going  directly in UBUNTU to address.me i see homepage on my website

Thanks,
Yosef

Comment: Can you post the network configuration of your VM?

Comment: How can i find network configuration of my VM?

Comment: i have 'Nat' option in network adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the IP address of the Ubuntu system (the host machine) to the Windows hosts file. It's location will vary depending on your version of Windows. See: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29)

You'd add a line like this:

```
<IP_address_of_Ubuntu> address.me
```

I think this should work in NAT mode, just check the default gateway of your network card under Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have your guest setup to have NAT networking. You should configure your guest networking to be bridged. This will allow your client to obtain an IP address from your main network and then allow your client and server to communicate.

Comment: Thanks, I have Nat network, How can i test if Nat network working and if not, why not(maybe i should setup https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking )?

Comment: @Yose: It is easier if you can change the guest network to bridged.